# Relation between OSI layers and Java

Tags: java, network-programming

This is a theoretical question indeed. As a Java programmer which layer I need to focus for writing network programs & why ?

Comment: Since you've already got sockets, you work from the 5th level up.

Comment: I would look at Java Network Programming and not worry about the OSI layers too much.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have some degree of understanding of all layers (for example, it's pretty helpful to have an understanding of the logical network addressing in Layer 3).

But generally, you will be focusing on the high level layers (layers 5, 6 and 7).

Having said all that, it is in my experience relatively rare for the OSI layers to be referenced directly in Java development projects.

Comment: Well actually probably layer 4-7 (4 is transport, so the Socket interface is related to that, since TCP is squarely in layer 4).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't need to worry about OSI layers at all since the project collapsed in about 1994 after the commercialisation of the Internet and the victory of TCP/IP. OSI is now of historical interest only.

What you should be worrying about is the *TCP/IP* reference model, which isn't the same as the OSI model, but unlike the OSI model it actually describes something real.

From the Java point of view there is practically nothing about either model that need concern you, as you only deal with TCP and UDP at the transport layer, and application protocols which you either use via APIs, for example DNS, or write yourself.